# How can I have a button to go to my app in the amazon store?

Tags: performance

I'm maiking a puzzle app and plan on having a upgrade button.  I have aversion for Google play and kindle fire.  On Google play I have the upgrade button bring up the google play store where my app is being sold.

I would like to do this for the kindle, so it would go to the amazon app store.  Tried to Googl eit but did not find any information.  I'v seen it done on other apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link was helpful for me.

http://www.webpronews.com/link-to-the-amazon-appstore-from-within-your-app-2012-04

e.g.

amzn://apps/android?asin=AppASIN#